Getting error with conda create environment from custom channel
I have download all packages and made a custom channel from it by following the instruction

    conda install conda-build


Organize all the packages in subdirectories for the platforms you wish to serve. Below is an example of what this may look like:
channel

└── win-64
    └── package-1.0-0.tar.bz2
    ....

Run conda index on the channel root directory:
conda index channel
However, when I recreate the environment from the local channel(specified in env.yml),
name: myenv
channels:
  - file:///C:/Dev/python-distro/py311/conda_channel/win-64


> conda env create -n myenv --offline -f env.yml

However, I was flooded with subdir mismatch complain.
output
channels:

file:///C:/mylocal channel folder

defaults

conda-forge
Platform: win-64
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): | subdir mismatch
subdir mismatch
subdir mismatch
....
subdir mismatch
The environment finally got installed


Anyone hit this issue before, and please help.

I am seeing the same issue as you regarding subdir mismatch. When you say "the environment finally got installed" - do you mean as far as you can tell there are not issues with the environment after the install finished? Yes there is an error relating to subdir mismatch, but does it cause any noticeable problems? (I don't yet know if this is a "problem" or just a warning message yet.)
